# How to convert HTML to MHTML using Python?

Tags: python, html, ms-word, mhtml

How to convert HTML to MS Word compatible format especially the Image ? 
Basically I need to convert HTML (Generated from TinyMCE) To MS Word Doc with Images etc (non URL images) and I figured out that MS Word doesn't support Data URI HTML standards . MHTML seems to be a a good option ? 
How can I convert a HTML with Images to MHTML using Python ?

Comment: I can't imagine anyone actually *wanting* to use MHTML (.mht files) if they can possibly avoid it.  It's way obsolete, it was *never* a standard, it's not widely supported, and it has no future.  There *has* to be a better alternative.  IMHO...

Comment: Quite true but its for an inconvenient requirement :)

Comment: Q: Have you considered RTF?  It's also a Microsoft format, it also supports embedded images ... and it has a Python module: http://pyrtf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Will have a look however my source is HTML so I thouhght HTML MHTML would be the easiest .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim Golden's tips on using IE own object may solve this case : http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/create-an-mhtml-archive.html

But actually, I also looking for a cross platform solution for this.